# How to remove iCheck checked state on Bootstrap modal when hidden?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-modal, icheck

I try to remove iCheck `checked` state on a Bootstrap modal, but many times I try, I failed.

I use iCheck for input type checkbox and radio.

So this is the modal code:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form role="form" id="form-swab" class="form-horizontal" action="tambah">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="swab_parameter" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Parameter Uji</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="swab_parameter[]" id="swab_parameter_tpc" value="TPC">
                        TPC
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="swab_parameter[]" id="swab_parameter_coliform" value="Coliform">
                        Coliform
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="hasil_swab_tpc">
                    <label for="swab_tpc" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hasil TPC</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" id="swab_tpc" name="swab_tpc" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasil Analisa TPC">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="hasil_swab_coliform">
                    <label for="swab_coliform" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hasil Coliform</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" id="swab_coliform" name="swab_coliform" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasil Analisa Coliform">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <input type="hidden" name="swab_ID" id="swab_ID" />
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="button-close-swab" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-swab">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal swab -->
```

I toggle the modal with `hashchange` (`jquery.ba-bbq.min.js` from https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq). This js load in the footer.

Javascript code (load in the footer as `site.js`):

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var host = window.location.hostname;

$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
        var hash = $.param.fragment();

        if(hash == 'tambah'){
            if(path.search('mikro/swab') > 0){
                $('#myModal .modal-header .modal-title').text('Input Data Swab');
                $('#myModal .modal-footer #submit-swab').text('Simpan');
                $('#myModal #form-swab').attr('action','tambah');        
            }
            // other else if
        }
        // other else if

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        window.history.pushState(null,null,path);
        $('#myModal form').find("input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], textarea, select").val("");
        $('#myModal form').show();
        $('input').iCheck('uncheck');
    });

});

$('#swab_parameter_tpc, #swab_parameter_coliform').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});

$('#swab_parameter_tpc').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    $('#hasil_swab_tpc').show('slow');
});

$('#swab_parameter_coliform').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    $('#hasil_swab_coliform').show('slow');
});

$('#swab_parameter_coliform').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    $('#hasil_swab_coliform').hide('slow');
});

$('#swab_parameter_ym').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    $('#hasil_swab_ym').hide('slow');
});
```

The problem is: when I open the modal, checked the checkbox and close the modal, then open the modal again, the checkbox is still in `checked` state, it should be back to uncheck. I try use `$('input').iCheck('uncheck');` but not work.

Is there something wrong about my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem appear on javascript, I try to reorder the script just like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('input').iCheck('uncheck');
    window.history.pushState(null,null,path);
    $('#myModal form').find("input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], textarea, select").val("");
    $('#myModal form').show();
});
```

And the script works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet, not sure why your code doesn't work on your end, but your code was working in here. Try to review how you toggle your modal. And try to specify the `<input>` elements that you want to initialize with `iCheck`

```js
$('#swab_parameter_tpc, #swab_parameter_coliform').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#myModal form').find("input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], textarea, select").val("");
    $('#myModal form').show();
    $('input').iCheck('uncheck');
  });

  $('#swab_parameter_tpc').on('ifChecked', function(event){
      $('#hasil_swab_tpc').show('slow');
  });

  $('#swab_parameter_coliform').on('ifChecked', function(event){
      $('#hasil_swab_coliform').show('slow');
  });

  $('#swab_parameter_coliform').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
      $('#hasil_swab_coliform').hide('slow');
  });

  $('#swab_parameter_ym').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
      $('#hasil_swab_ym').hide('slow');
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.2/icheck.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Try me</a> 
 
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form role="form" id="form-swab" class="form-horizontal" action="tambah">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="swab_parameter" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Parameter Uji</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="swab_parameter[]" id="swab_parameter_tpc" value="TPC">
                        TPC
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="swab_parameter[]" id="swab_parameter_coliform" value="Coliform">
                        Coliform
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="hasil_swab_tpc">
                    <label for="swab_tpc" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hasil TPC</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" id="swab_tpc" name="swab_tpc" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasil Analisa TPC">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="hasil_swab_coliform">
                    <label for="swab_coliform" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hasil Coliform</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" id="swab_coliform" name="swab_coliform" class="form-control" placeholder="Hasil Analisa Coliform">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <input type="hidden" name="swab_ID" id="swab_ID" />
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="button-close-swab" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-swab">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal swab -->
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't know why these code not working for me. Additional information, I toggle the modal with `hashchange` (jquery.ba-bbq.min.js from https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq). Is there any conflict because off this?